# how to reboot the application when there is a change in last modification time of an accesed file in that application

Tags: c++

I'm new to thread programming. I'm trying to create an application which continually checks the Last Modification time of some file and exits the program when that time has changed.

Please find my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
#define NUM_THREADS 2

void *getFileCreationTime(void *path) {
    const char *pt;
    pt=(const char *)path;
    struct stat attr;
    stat("/home/utthunga/shmrp.cpp", &attr);
    while(1){
        char  *timestamp= ctime(&attr.st_mtime);
        if(timestamp)
        {
            cout<<"Last modified time: %s"<< ctime(&attr.st_mtime)<<endl;
            cout<<"No changes has been made to the file"<<endl;
            sleep(4);
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"Last modified time: %s"<< ctime(&attr.st_mtime)<<endl;
            cout<<"Time stamp has been changed"<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int i;
    int rc;

    for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS-1; i++ ) 
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getFileCreationTime, (void *)i);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what changes I have to implement in order to check the last modification time of that file continually and exit the application when that time has changed?

Comment: Taking a step back, what are you really trying to achieve here? It is quite an ugly approach. Have you considered using signals to communicate between processes instead? Or sockets?

Answer (score 1):

After you retrieve the file's modification time the first time, you need to save it so you can compare it to subsequent values retrieved afterwards.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void* getFileCreationTime(void *) { 
    const char *path = "/home/utthunga/shmrp.cpp";
    struct stat attr;
    if (stat(path, &attr) < 0) {
        cout << "stat error" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    time_t mtime = attr.st_mtime;
    cout << "Last modified time: " << ctime(&mtime) << endl;
    while(1) {
        sleep(4);
        if (stat(path, &attr) < 0) {
            cout << "stat error" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        if (attr.st_mtime != mtime) {
            cout << "Time stamp has been changed" << endl;
            exit(0);
        } else {
            cout << "No changes have been made to the file" << endl;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: thank you. that worked fine for me. The application exits when there is a change in time stamp. But i would like add some more implementations to it. i.e i would like to restart the closed application from another application using system () call. can you please guide me how i could do it??.